OBS Studio Plugins Not Showing After Installation on NixOS
Question
I'm trying to install OBS Studio along with several plugins on my NixOS system, but the plugins do not appear in the OBS interface after installation. Here’s what I've done so far:
Installation Steps
I modified my configuration.nix to include OBS Studio and the following plugins:
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    obs-studio
    obs-studio-plugins.obs-shaderfilter
    obs-studio-plugins.obs-composite-blur
    obs-studio-plugins.obs-scale-to-sound
    obs-studio-plugins.obs-move-transition
    obs-studio-plugins.obs-gradient-source
    obs-studio-plugins.obs-backgroundremoval
  ];

}

After making these changes, I ran:
sudo nixos-rebuild switch

Are there additional steps I can take to troubleshoot or ensure the plugins load correctly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Found the solution on:
[https://wiki.nixos.org/w/index.php?title=OBS_Studio][1]
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    obs-studio
  ];

  environment.systemPackages = [
    (pkgs.wrapOBS {
      plugins = with pkgs.obs-studio-plugins; [
        obs-backgroundremoval
        obs-shaderfilter
        obs-composite-blur
        obs-scale-to-sound
        obs-move-transition
        obs-gradient-source
      ];
    })
  ];
}

